# What would the graph look like if the electrodes were non-equidistant from the depolarization wave?

Tags: physiology, heart, electrocardiogram

[image]

Hypothetically speaking using the diagram above. If the negative electrode was very far away from this cardiomyocyte and the positive electrode was right next to it. What would the voltage graph look like when the dipole goes towards the positive electrode (depolarization wave). Would it just be a smaller scale of the same shape?

Comment: Although your question isn't off topic here, I think you would get better answers in the Physics or Electrical Engineering exchange.